# INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}'

Tags: python, logging, conda

Currently I get a lot of these INFO messages when I update packages:

```
$ conda update --all --yes
Fetching package metadata .................
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\anacondadir:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ipython:   6.0.0-py35_1 --> 6.1.0-py35_0
    nbconvert: 5.1.1-py35_0 --> 5.2.1-py35_0
    testpath:  0.3-py35_0   --> 0.3.1-py35_0

testpath-0.3.1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.31 MB/s
ipython-6.1.0- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   2.77 MB/s
nbconvert-5.2. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.36 MB/s
INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\anacondadir', env_name: 'None', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'user'
INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\anacondadir', env_name: 'None', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'user'
```

Is there some way to hide (or better: adressing/fixing the root cause) of these messages?

Possibly important data:

```
conda 4.3.21 
menuinst 1.4.7
requests 2.14.2 
CPython 3.5.3 
Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
```

Comment: I've the same problem and I'm not sure if it's a problem. I hope not, at least it's saying INFO but still looks kind of inappropriate.

Comment: I haven't been able to identify any problems resultant from this issue...That said I'm still having it despite having posted the only upvoted answer :L. It appears to have something to do with updating `ipython`/`jupyter` + having reinstalled anaconda @ some point.

Answer (score 3):

So first off, the following will get rid of those `DEBUG` messages, **but it will also get rid of the progress-bars & most of the rest of `conda update`'s `stdout`.**

I'd suggest **not doing the following & just sorta dealing with them until updating conda fixes itself** which will likely eventually happen. This question has been navigated to by almost 1K people a month; I haven't looked at the official repo but I'll bet this is on the radar for future releases.

This will make conda quiet & get rid of the `DEBUG` messages:

```
conda config --set quiet True
```