# Anaconda3 conda command error menuinst_win32

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm installing anaconda python 3, version 4.4.0 on Windows machines.  The installs finishes normally.  But I'm getting errors when I try to use conda to update or to create virtual environments.  Package resolution completes and downloads the packages but then hangs for a long time before throwing out a load of errors like so:

`conda create -n py2 python=2.7 anaconda`

> INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
> prefix: 'c:\anaconda\envs\py2', env_name: 'py2', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'system'
> INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
> prefix: 'c:\anaconda\envs\py2', env_name: 'py2', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'system'
> INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
> prefix: 'c:\anaconda\envs\py2', env_name: 'py2', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'system'
> INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
> prefix: 'c:\anaconda\envs\py2', env_name: 'py2', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'system'
> INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
> prefix: 'c:\anaconda\envs\py2', env_name: 'py2', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'system'
> INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
> prefix: 'c:\anaconda\envs\py2', env_name: 'py2', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'system'
> INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
> prefix: 'c:\anaconda\envs\py2', env_name: 'py2', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'system'

The environment will still have been created but this hanging and waiting is really becoming a problem.  I assume this is a fairly new bug because I've been installing anaconda and using conda for quite a while and never seen this error before.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335616/info-menuinst-win32-init-182-menu-name-anacondapy-ver-platform but can't make it a duplicate because I haven't got any useful answers yet...

Answer (score 3):

I posted this to the anaconda github page.  Apparently this is an issue with the displayed output but isn't actually an error in the install.  The virtual environment installations and updates do work, although they are slower than normal.