# DEBUG menuinst_win32 when running conda update --all

Tags: python, debugging, installation, anaconda

When I executed "conda update --all", I got the following debug messages. I don't see any misbehavior in my Python or Spyder installation. Does anyone knows why we get this debug messages sometimes, what are they warning us about?

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: / DEBUG menuinst_win32:**init**(198): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\python.exe', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py', '--reset']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:**init**(198): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\python.exe', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py', '--reset']
| DEBUG menuinst_win32:**init**(198): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\python.exe', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py', '"%USERPROFILE%/"']
/ DEBUG menuinst_win32:**init**(198): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\python.exe', 'C:\Users\usuario\Miniconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py', '--reset']

Comment: Is it may related to the fact that my user (usuario) does not have admin permissions, so it fails to create shortcuts?

Comment: I just started getting the same message. It asks for an admin passoword for every DEBUG message. Have you recently reinstalled anaconda? I found these two posts from three years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879771/anaconda3-conda-command-error-menuinst-win32 and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335616/info-menuinst-win32-init-182-menu-name-anacondapy-ver-platform  and this post on anaconda github from a year ago https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3903 but can't find anything in there that constitutes a real explanation/ solution.

Comment: I have this same issue, did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: No, I did not figure anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

The following command solved this issue for me:

> conda clean --yes --all